# Netbeans Container deletion operation fails to perform properly?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans6.8, netbeans6.7

I'm trying to delete a JPanel from my mailPanel under [FrameView] in Netbeans??!  When I delete this JPanel it just deletes this from Inspector view, it does not unlink and delete all the components it has auto-generated as a result of creating those controllers inside the JPanel and the JPanel itself and leaves my initial code with all the rubbish that were meant to be deleted.  What should I do to safely delete everything associated with this JPanel deletion??!  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Goto `inspector view` > `Right click the panel` > `Delete`

Comment: I do that but when I delete, my whole code gets filled with errors from lines referencing that JPanel and its contents!  The worst part that everything's in the auto-generated area and can't be touched!

Comment: If your're gonna delete a jpanel, you should make sure that its no more used, how can you delete a component that is being used in the program? and reference to auto-generated code, you can edit that by `right-clicking` the component and select `customiz-code`.

Comment: suppose if you have a code snippet `jtexfield1.settext("test")`, this `jtextfield` was in the jpanel you deleted,so the above snippet will show error since the `jtextfield` will be deleted with the jpanel ~!